# upload icon is not applying for use tag in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, slds, static-resources, urlfor, svg-icon

I have uploaded Icon's in static resource as a zip format and when i am trying to get upload icon from them while saving component it is throwing error.

> No function found for key: URLFOR: Source

```
<svg class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon_left" aria-hidden="true">
   <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Resource.slds, '/utility/symbols.svg#upload')}"></use>
</svg>Upload Files</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URLFOR is a Visualforce formula. For Lighting, it would simply be:

```
<use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="{!$Resource.slds+'/utility/symbols.svg#upload'}" />
```

Note that this is not necessary, as SLDS icons are built-in to Lightning:

```
<lightning-icon iconName="utility:upload" />
```